# Loading spinner relative to jQuery mobile dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog, css-position

Is it possible to have a loading spinner, called by `$.mobile.loading`, within a jQuery mobile dialog, and have it position **relative** to that dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible directly, but you could do it in a hacky way :

1. On the `pageinit` of the dialog, clone the `<div/>` with `.ui-loader` class.

   ```
   var loader = $(".ui-loader").clone();
   ```
2. Then add it into our dialog, like this :

   ```
   $page.find('[data-role="content"]').html(loader); //$page is the dialog
   ```
3. Create a class called `.ui-loader-altered` and add `position:relative` to it. Add the class to the loader inside dialog. This will make loader stay within dialog.

   ```
   $page.find(".ui-loader").addClass("ui-loader-altered");
   ```
4. Now that you've got the dialog, why dont you show it up?

   ```
   $page.find(".ui-loader-altered").show();
   ```

Full code :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#second", function () {
    $page = $(this);
    $(this).on("click", "#show", function () {
        //clone
        var loader = $(".ui-loader").clone();
        //add to dialog
        $page.find('[data-role="content"]').html(loader);
        //add class which makes dialog position relative to div
        $page.find(".ui-loader").addClass("ui-loader-altered");
        //show it up
        $page.find(".ui-loader-altered").show();
    })

});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/P2XJt/3/

Comment: I wanted the loading dialog thing though, called by `$.mobile.loading`

Comment: Wait a second.  No.  This only works with the spinner, not the dialog.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I don't quite get you

Comment: Also, when I try adding line breaks to the html, it hides the page.

Comment: Well, I would like the loading **dialog** found [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/loader.html)

Comment: So all you want is just a dialog with some text underneath it? Or am I misunderstanding your needs

Comment: No I think everything is fine.  Thanks!